# Display specific node type in different path

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have created a new content-type `Document Template`. I need to display the contents of type `Document template` in a different path.

```
localhost/site_name/document_templates
```

not in

```
localhost/site_name.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `View` with `Page` display. Set its `Path` to `document_templates`. Add a `Filter criteria` for `Content: Type (= Document Template)`. Hit save. Now visit your url `localhost/site_name/document_templates`. You will see your content of type `Document Template`.

Comment: I tried what you suggest. Yeah it's working. Thanks to that. The Nodes of Content Type 'Document' was displayed on path 'localhost/site_name/document_templates' , but it was still displayed in 'localhost/site_name' . How will I  omit that in the original path?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pathauto module and configure it so this content type automatically gets the right path settings by default when creating a node.
https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto